# Finding Radon Nikodym derivative for a function of the measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I have a question regarding finding the Radon Nikodym derivative of a measure w.r.t. another measure constructed from the first one. The situation is the following:

Take a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, with $P$ being a probability measure. Now construct a second measure from $P$ via  $P \mapsto Q := f(P)$, with a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function $f$ being chosen in a way such that the resulting $Q$ again is a probability measure over $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$. Furthermore, $f$ is required to conserve the kernel of $P$, i.e. $\{A \subset \mathcal{A}: P(A) = 0\} = \{A \subset \mathcal{A}: Q(A) = 0\}$.
(Take for instance $Q(A) = \sqrt{P(A)} \; \forall A \in \mathcal{A}$, for the monotonicity with which the square root is increasing amounts for the $\sigma$-additivity, and $Q(\Omega) = 1$ as well as $Q(\emptyset) = 0$). Hence these two measures are $\sigma$-finite by definition, and clearly equivalent.

My question is now, is there a way to determine the Radon Nikodym derivative $g = \frac{dQ}{dP}$, or $\tilde{g} = \frac{dP}{dQ}$ ? I don't know exactly but I guess that $g = f'$ is too easy and would not work ?

A first idea was that one could write $g$ as a decomposition of simple functions but it is not quite clear how to explicitly expand the simple functions into characteristic functions since I do not know which sets from $\mathcal{A}$ to choose.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: $f(P)$ is rarely a measure. $\sqrt {P(A)}$ is certainly not  a measure except in trivial cases (like a degenerate measure $P$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kavi, but I do not quite understand why $\sqrt{\cdot} \circ P(A)$ should not be a measure, I mean which of the axioms did I miss ?
I'm pretty sure it is non-negative, $\sigma$-additive and gives 0 at the empty set. In additions it gives 1 at the whole space, making it a probability measure, right ?

Comment: If $f$ is measurable function such that $f(P)$ is countably additive for every probability measure $P$ then $f(x)=x$ for all $x$. So your question is quite meaningless.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Since there must hold $f(P)(A \overset{\cdot}{\cup} B) = f(P(A) + P(B)) \overset{!}{=} f(P(A)) + f(P(B))$, $f$ must be linear. On the other hand, for $f(P)$ to be a probability measure, we need $f(P)$ to take the values 1 at 1, and 0 at zero, uniquely determining $f$ to be the identity. 
Thanks for clarifying !